# Spreadsheet API feed.getEntries() CellEntry

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

When trying out the Example from Google in Android Studio i got the following error:

```
Error:(52, 46) error: incompatible types
required: CellEntry
found:    SpreadsheetEntry
```

at Line:

```
// Iterate through each cell, printing its value.
for (CellEntry cell : feed.getEntries()) {
```

I used the Example "Work with list-based feeds" from https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data

Also, is it possible to get data from a public spreadsheet without authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I could be a typo in the documentation. In the same page there is another example:

```
CellFeed cellFeed = service.getFeed(cellFeedUrl, CellFeed.class);

    // Iterate through each cell, printing its value.
    for (CellEntry cell : cellFeed.getEntries()) {....
```

As you can see the object containing the feed is from the Class CellFedd. 
Try to check in your code the object that contains the results change it.

When making requests to the api, i think you have to be authenticated even if the file is public.